# Could not find method mavencentral() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler

Tags: android-studio, maven-central

I was trying to sync this to gradle, I was getting a lot of errors
I was resolving everything by using Stackoverflow, But stuck at this specific ERROR
[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the error

Comment: I attached the screenshot though. Please help me

Comment: Please share more details in readable form. Don't use screenshots as the main source of information for a question

Answer (score 0):

Should be `mavenCentral` (uppercase `C`), not `mavencentral`.